# Definition of subsequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need help understanding the following definition:

> We say that a sequence $b:\Bbb N\rightarrow S$ is a subsequence of a sequence $a:\Bbb N\rightarrow S$ if there exists a strictly increasing sequence $p:\Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb N$ such that $b=a\circ p.$

So if I take for example that $a$ is a sequence of natural numbers and $b$ is a sequence of even numbers, then what is $p$ here?

Comment: did you understand the explanation?

Comment: @ItamarGreen Yes.

Comment: excellent. (It's good I can explain it because I have a big calculus test tomorrow XD)

Comment: @ItamarGreen Good luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, $p$ is exactly like $b$:

$$b = {2,4,6,8,...}$$
and

$$a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...}$$

then $p$ would denote the indices to select from $a$ in order to create $b$

the even numbers are at the second,fourth,sixth,... indices: ${1,(2),3,(4),...}$
where the numbers in $()$ are the even indices.

then the sequence $b$ is a sequence of *selected* values, and the way they are selected is related to the indices, which are presented as a sequence of integers: $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Just take a $k\in \Bbb N$ and send it to $2k$, in symbols $p(k) =2k$

Answer (score 3):

If $b$ is the even naturals, and $a$ is the naturals, then 
$$
p:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\\
k\mapsto2k
$$
and thus $a\circ p:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}=S$ is exactly the even terms in the sequence $a$. The increasing condition is to make sure what you get is really a "sequence" in the sense that you have some indexing set that marches along.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that *b* is indeed a subsequence of *a*, then *p* is the list of the indices of the members of *a*, that are in *b*. This is just the general definition.

However I assume that you had a slightly different example in mind, namely that *b* is the subsequence of *a*, of all the even numbers of *a*. *p* is therefore the list of the indices of the members of *a*, that are even.

Example: *a* = 1,3,2,4,9,2,...., and therefore *b* = 2,4,2, ...., and therefore *p* = 3,4,6,...  In this example *a* does not follow an arithmetic pattern.

(I apologize for writing in plain. I don't know how to format properly).